# How can I have decorations also appearing in the legend?

Tags: pgfplots, legend, decorations

I am trying to use decorations to add markers to some lines. The reason for using decorations, rather than simply markers, is that the data points I'm plotting are very dense: filtering them beforehand is not a viable option, and using markers results in an incomprehensible blob of overlapping things. Good results can be obtained doing something like the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xmin=0, xmax=5,
ymin=0, ymax=2,
postaction={decoration={markings,
    mark=between positions 0 and 5 step 0.05
    with { \fill circle[radius=2pt]; }},
    decorate}
]
\addplot[samples=500]{1};
\addlegendentry{Plot 1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, the MWE above produces a legend where the decoration **does not** appear. How can I make the decoration appear also in the legend?

Comment: try adding other plots before and after your plot, you can mark selectively instead of this fragile method

Comment: Try `legend style={mark=*,mark size=2pt}`. But maybe you can use markers instead decoration: `\addplot[samples=500,mark=*,mark repeat=25]{1};`

Comment: @esdd, do you want to write your comment as an answer? If not, I would vote to close the question as being solved in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the marks to the `every axis legend style` using

```
legend style={mark=*,mark size=2pt}
```

as a key for the `axis` environment.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}% <- added, see the documentation 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xmin=0, xmax=5,
ymin=0, ymax=2,
postaction={decoration={markings,
    mark=between positions 0 and 5 step 0.05
    with { \fill circle[radius=2pt]; }},
    decorate},
    legend style={mark=*,mark size=2pt}% <- added
]
\addplot[samples=500]{1};
\addlegendentry{Plot 1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

But I would suggest to use markers instead `decoration`. You can reduce the number of marks using `mark repeat=25`. Then only each 25th point is marked.

[image]

Then the first mark on the plot is not clipped at the axis border.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}% <- added, see the documentation 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xmin=0, xmax=5,
ymin=0, ymax=2
]
\addplot[samples=500,mark=*,mark repeat=25]{1};% <- changed
\addlegendentry{Plot 1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```